# RN corrupted after the second activity quit

Tags: android, react-native

I use RN 0.36 for Android app. My application have two activities: MainActivity - application entry point and second for process Share page intent from browser. Share page can be started when MainActivity already is started or not.
Both activities use same RN component. I mean what is registered with AppRegistry.registerComponent.

Issue Description
1 App is started, so MainActivity is active, RN started.
2 Switch to browser - MainActivity is paused.
3 Start ShareActivity from browser. We have our app resumed, but with ShareActivity foreground. Here we use some scenes from RN part and later finish activity with Activity.finish(). We returned to browser.
4. Switch to our app. We can see scenes from 1 (right stored from previous state) or some other from 3 (wrong state), but as result of action with any UI component we have:
'W ReactNativeJS: Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the...'

Expected Results
RN part of MainActivity stored previous state and still processed is fine.

Is there any mistake in this usage? Or how can I solve this? Thanks very much!

Additional Information

React Native version: 0.36.1
Platform(s) (iOS, Android, or both?): Android
Operating System (macOS, Linux, or Windows?): Windows